# Display MAX and 2nd MAX SALARY from the EMPLOYEE table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT max(salary),
(SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE SALARY NOT IN(SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE)) as 2ND_MAX_SALARY;
```

This is giving me the error: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please make sure to tag your question appropriately.  I removed the SQL Server tag from your question assuming, since you also tagged with Oracle SQL Developer, that you mean Oracle (they are not the same).

Answer (score 0):

You want the top 2 of your table ordered by one of the columns (the `FETCH NEXT` clause is available from Oracle 12c R1)

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 2
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

Use

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 2
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

if you want to return all employees that have the 1st or 2nd highest salary: There might only be one highest salary amount in the company, but more than one employee who gets that amount. Those rows are the ties.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Oracle database version lower than 12c, `rank` analytic function might help.

For sample rows:

```
SQL> select * from employee order by salary desc;

ENAME          SALARY
---------- ----------
KING             5000     --> highest salary
FORD             3000     --> Ford and Scott "share" the 2nd
SCOTT            3000     --> highest salary
JONES            2975
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450
ALLEN            1600
TURNER           1500
MILLER           1300
WARD             1250
MARTIN           1250
ADAMS            1100
JAMES             950
SMITH             800

14 rows selected.
```

In a subquery (or a CTE, as I did), *calculate* rank for each salary and then, in the main query, select rows that rank as to top salaries:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select ename,
  3            salary,
  4            rank() over (order by salary desc) rnk
  5     from employee
  6    )
  7  select ename, salary
  8  from temp
  9  where rnk <= 2
 10  order by rnk desc;

ENAME          SALARY
---------- ----------
SCOTT            3000
FORD             3000
KING             5000

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MAX(salary) AS max_salary, 
      (SELECT MAX(salary) 
       FROM employee 
       WHERE salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(salary) 
                            FROM employee
                           )
      ) AS 2nD_max_salary 
FROM employee;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.